# make keyword into link automatically, globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, keyword

is there a way to make a every instance of a word automatically turn into a link?

so for instance, everytime I write "apple", it is automatically formatted to `<a href="www.apple.com" class="whatever" target="_blank">apple</a>`

I'm assuming i could use javascript or possibly jquery.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

very very simple example...

jQuery

```
var span = $('span');
    span.html(function(i,html){
        replaceTextWithHTMLLinks(html);
    }); // jQuery version 1.4.x


function replaceTextWithHTMLLinks(text) {
  var exp = /(apple)/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a class='link' href='http://www.$1.com' target='_blank' >$1</a>"); 
}
```

html

```
<span> 
An apple a day, makes 7 apples a week!
</span>
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/6NDqv/)

Comment: That will replace the HTML of all spans on the page. Use `each` on the spans instead to avoid that.

Comment: first of all, how would `each()` solve your problem?. second, that is not the point here and just an example. I could even say `$('body');`. The OP didn't mention any of it. :)

Comment: If you use `each` to iterate through all of the spans and replace their HTML individually (though you'd probably want to test for the presence of the keyword before doing so), then it will not replace all of the spans on the page with the same content...

Comment: oh I see. It's because of the variable I'm using. Updated to fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple jQuery plugin that should do the trick.  It will only select text nodes so that if you have an element with a class `apple` or id `apple` it won't get replaced.  Additionally, if you have a link `<a href="#">apple</a>` it won't get replaced (might be a little more  than you need, but I thought I'd post it anyway):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.replacetext = function(target, replacement) {
         // Get all text nodes:
         var $textNodes = this
                 .find("*")
                 .andSelf()
                 .contents()
                 .filter(function() {
                     return this.nodeType === 3 &&
                         !$(this).parent("a").length;
                 });

         // Iterate through the text nodes, replacing the content
         // with the link:
         $textNodes.each(function(index, element) {
             var contents = $(element).text();
             contents = contents.replace(target, replacement);
             $(element).replaceWith(contents);
         });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$("body").replacetext(/apple/gi, "<a href='http://www.$&.com'>$&</a>");
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/VmHjJ/

Note that this could become inefficient rather quickly due to the use of the `$("*")` selector.  If possible, you should replace it with something more specific (or remove the `.find("*").andSelf()` portion entirely and pass the plugin a more specific selector).

Comment: No, this looks perfect! I'll try it out in a sec

Comment: Works very nice here, except for selectors which contain some iframe: _permission denied to access property "document"_ .