# replace a word throughout the body tag but dont replace the word which is present inside the tag attribute like alt, image path, href,title etc

Tags: jquery

I wanted to replace a word "demo text" by '<span class="nowrap-text">demo text</span>

I tried the following code:

```
var bodyText = $("body").html().replace("demo text",'<span class="nowrap-text">demo text</span>');
$("body").html(bodyText);
```

but the above code resulting the following issue:

```
<a herf="" title="<span class="nowrap-text">demo text</span>" >demo text</a>
```

it needs to change the text inside the  tag not inside the attribute "title"

its just an example but it need to apply for different tags and throughout the body wherever the text is present...

Comment: try escape quote : replace("\"demo text\"","\'demo text\'");

Comment: Can you please add your relevant HTML?

Comment: I wanted to replace a word "demo text" by<span class="nowrap-text">demo text</span>

I tried the following code:

var bodyText = $("body").html();
$(bodyText).replace("demo text",'<span class="nowrap-text">demo text</span>');
but the above code resulting the following issue:

<a herf="" title="<span class="nowrap-text">demo text</span>" >demo text</a>;

Comment: in stead of `$("body").html();` try `$("body").text();`

Comment: @spluf am again replacing the whole content to body also with all the tag...

If am trying to access through text then how it will be possible to place each text in each tag...

Comment: @spluf i have edited the code again pls have a look again...

Comment: please edit your question and add the body of your html page as well, or better yet, if you could add the code on https://jsfiddle.net or https://plnkr.co/ it would be even better

Comment: @Salketer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754467/make-keyword-into-link-automatically-globally not using any attribube having same text...

Comment: @TanushreeBehera that "not using any attribute" part is implied... Have you tried the answer there at least? It does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @Salketer yes i tried and it is showing same issue...

Comment: I've made a snippet to prove you it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some regular expression like this one:

```
(<[^<>]+>[^<>]*)(demo text)([^<>]*</[^<>]+>)
```

and make a global replacement:

```
data = data.replace(
    /(<[^<>]+>[^<>]*)(demo text)([^<>]*<\/[^<>]+>)/img, 
    '$1<span class="nowrap-text">$2</span>$3'
);
```

It won't cover all use cases but maybe it'll be enough for you.

Jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ehpc/jb4mbv2g/.

Comment: Its working great... 
thanks a lot....

Comment: the code worked fine but in the following scenario its not working 

<span>demo text<sup>®</sup></span>

Comment: for the following scenario the cod is not working

<span>demo text<span>click here</span></span>

Comment: i have updated https://jsfiddle.net/jb4mbv2g/3/ please have a look.

 i have added a span inside <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

check this plunker, it works fine for me:

https://plnkr.co/edit/6V0WpI2x8BsfzxkOcc94?p=preview

code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bodyText = $("body").html();
  console.log(bodyText)

$("body").html(bodyText.replace(" demo text ",'<span class="nowrap-text"> replaced text </span>'));
})
```

html:

```
    <html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="demoText" title="demo text">
      <p>some demo text here</p>
    </a>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Edit:**
i made a small modification for the case in which your have attributes with the same name as that text. Just by adding spaces before and after the text it will ignore attributes(because attributes shouldn't start or end with spaces).

Comment: Thanks...

some title conatins like
title="the demo text replace here"

in these case it will not fruitful

Comment: in that case you can try @ehpc's solution by using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [make keyword into link automatically, globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754467/make-keyword-into-link-automatically-globally)

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.replacetext = function(target, replacement) {
         // Get all text nodes:
         var $textNodes = this
                 .find("*")
                 .andSelf()
                 .contents()
                 .filter(function() {
                     return this.nodeType === 3;
                 });

         // Iterate through the text nodes, replacing the content
         // with the link:
         $textNodes.each(function(index, element) {
             var contents = $(element).text();
             contents = contents.replace(target, replacement);
             $(element).replaceWith(contents);
         });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('body').replacetext(/demo/gi,'<span class="red">demo</span>');
```

```css
.red{
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#demo">Link to the demo</a>
```

Comment: @slketer Thanks... yes it works

I was checking http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/6NDqv/ so i missedout http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/VmHjJ/ ,  apologize....